# I'd like to add a language button to my header. How can I insert it?

Tags: html, squarespace

With a lot of trial and error I finally created a language button for my Squarespace website in the style of the website.

The website in question: https://www.happylifeclinic.org and the button is currently in a markdown block just under the header image. I'd like to have it just right of the 'Contact" button and I can't, for the life of me, figure it out how and where to input the HTML code (I'm using GitHub Desktop and editing the HTML with Sublime 3).

If I left something out please let me know.

Comment: Client didn't want the dropdown anymore, I did, however, find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to shift the whole block of code `sqs-block` to the header section in HTML. I tried doing following from inspector and it works fine :

```
<nav id="mainNavigation" data-content-field="navigation-mainNav">
   <div class="collection active homepage">
      <a href="/">
      Acasa
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="collection">
      <a href="/ro/despre-noi/">
      Despre Noi
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="folder">
      <div class="folder-toggle" data-href="/ro/folder/servicii/">Servicii</div>
      <div class="subnav">
         <div class="collection">
            <a href="/ro/corporate/">
            Corporate
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="collection">
            <a href="/ro/adulti/">
            Adulti
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="collection">
            <a href="/ro/copii-si-adolescenti/">
            Copii si Adolescenti
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="collection">
            <a href="/ro/cuplu-si-familie/">
            Cuplu si Familie
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="collection">
            <a href="/ro/lgbtq/">
            LGBTQ
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="collection">
      <a href="/ro/contact/">
      Contact
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="sqs-block markdown-block sqs-block-markdown" data-block-type="44" id="block-yui_3_17_2_2_1515674166386_21002">
      <div class="sqs-block-content" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1515676082589_298">
         <div data-preserve-html-node="true" class="dropdown" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1515676082589_297">
            <button data-preserve-html-node="true" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1515676082589_296">Language</button>
            <div data-preserve-html-node="true" id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
               <a data-preserve-html-node="true" id="navEng" href="/en/index" class="language"><img data-preserve-html-node="true" id="imgNavEng" src="http://www.roemheld.de/IT/Data/Images/Address/Grossbritanien.gif" alt="ENG" class="img-thumbnail icon-small"></a>
               <a data-preserve-html-node="true" id="navEng" href="/ro/index" class="language"><img data-preserve-html-node="true" id="imgNavEng" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/59f333cc49fc2b47eddb3379/t/5a44df2e08522979a70abfa9/1514463022027/ro.png" alt="ENG" class="img-thumbnail icon-small"></a>
               <a data-preserve-html-node="true" id="navEng" href="/de/index" class="language"><img data-preserve-html-node="true" id="imgNavEng" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/59f333cc49fc2b47eddb3379/t/5a44dee6ec212d2c0937ff25/1514462950503/de.png" alt="ENG" class="img-thumbnail icon-small"></a>
               <a data-preserve-html-node="true" id="navEng" href="/it/index" class="language"><img data-preserve-html-node="true" id="imgNavEng" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/59f333cc49fc2b47eddb3379/t/5a47dcde9140b7ea14e11002/1514659038936/it.png" alt="ENG" class="img-thumbnail icon-small"></a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

You definitely need to work on CSS then to get it look right with its dropdown options.

Comment: I've tried to change the header code: `<div id="headerNav"><squarespace:navigation navigationId="mainNav" template="navigation" /></div>
        </div>` to your block, and it did insert it, however as you can see, it's nothing like the initial version.

Comment: You have done something wrong with CSS somewhere. you please generate a codepan block to show case what you had previously. i can then better help you guiding for what's wrong.

Comment: I didn't change anything in CSS, I only added added the code from above instead of the code in my previous comment.

Comment: ok share the codepen please. revert things on your website too. so that i can compare and check what went wrong.